# JSON string parameter not working

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-4, parameters, html5-canvas, json.net

I'm having some trobule with JSON parameter. Here's part of the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#deco").click(function () {
        var cap = document.getElementById('canvasVideo').toDataURL();

        var canvas = document.getElementById('captImage');
        var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
        var imageObj = new Image();

        imageObj.onload = function () {
            context.drawImage(imageObj, 0, 0);
        };
        imageObj.src = cap;

       //var cap = 'hardcoding' ; if i hardcode the text, and pass this as a parameter, it works.

        $.getJSON('/Home/decodeQR', { img : cap  },
            function (idDonante) {
                document.getElementById("result").value = idDonante;
            });
        });

</script>
```

In the server side, I've got the following:

```
    [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get)]
    public JsonResult decodeQR(string img)
    {

        var idDonante = getIDQR(Conversion.Base64StringToBitmap(img));

        return Json(idDonante, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

As it is mentioned in the code, if I hardcode the parameter it works. I think the problem is in the variable that gets the string from canvas.toDataURL(), but I am not sure.

EDIT: I have to mention, that as it is now, the JsonResult method on the server is never called, unless I hardcode img attribute.

Comment: Did you try the browser debugger to see what value is coming back from `document.getElementById('canvasVideo').toDataURL()`?

Comment: I tried with firebug, and the value is ok, it brings an image codified in a base64 string. I don't know what is going on with that.. :/

Comment: Hmm, and how does the value look when it gets to the server in the `img` variable?  It's possible it could be getting encoded oddly.

Comment: I think the format is not important, because I need it to be an string. (I do post-proccess the string on server side). The odd thing is that "cap" variable is assigned correctly. In order to test that I created another canvas, and assigned to the src attribute the value of "cap" and the image is copied ok. :/

Comment: Just saw your edit.  Do you know if a request is being triggered at all and if so if it is reaching the server?  The server could possibly be encountering an error before it gets to calling your action method.

Comment: You are right, it goes to the server bad it has an error and returns bad request. HTTP Error 400. The size of the request headers is too long.

Comment: Ah ok, so the server didn't like the format of the URL for some reason.  This can happen when sending more complex data via the URL and querystring.  Is the value in the URL being passed as a route value or in the querystring?

Comment: It seems as the head field on the request is been overflowed. So, I won't ever be able to send an RGB image in base64 to the server?

Comment: That is getting into a networking area that I am not to sure about.  What if you switch the GET to a POST?  I would think more data would be allowed via a POST.

Answer (score 0):

There is a limit to how long a URL can be. See here: [What is the maximum length of a URL in different browsers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/417142/what-is-the-maximum-length-of-a-url-in-different-browsers)

You should be POSTing the encoded image data to your server instead.